# My implementation of fgets reads actual content as fgets does but it reads garbage if NULL string is found in file?

Tags: c, file, null, fgets

I have implemented my own `fgets` (i.e `myfgets`). When there is NULL string in my file which has to be read by `myfgets` function then it print all the string (good) but with some garbage(bad), but if I use predefine `fgets` then there is no garbage. Below is my code and file content which has NULL string in it.

myfile

hello word **NULL** Good Morning     // if NULL is removed then its good

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *myfgets(char *Buffer_address,int size,FILE *fp)
{
    register int c;
    register char  *I_help_Notify_IfNotRead;
    I_help_Notify_IfNotRead = Buffer_address;

    while(--size>0 && (c=getc(fp))!=EOF )
    {
        if((*I_help_Notify_IfNotRead++=c)=='\n')
            break;
       *I_help_Notify_IfNotRead='\0';
    }

    return ( c==EOF && I_help_Notify_IfNotRead == Buffer_address ) ? NULL : Buffer_address;
}

int main()
{
    char ch[100];
    FILE *fp ;
    fp=fopen("myfile","r");
    char * pp=(myfgets(ch,100,fp));
    printf("%s",pp);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  // No need to close(fp) because exit does for us
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
hello word NULL Good Morning (good)

E����[�s^� (garbage)    // Why am I getting this but not with predefine fgets?
```

Comment: `*I_help_Notify_IfNotRead='\0';` should come after the loop. Also, if your file is empty, the behavior is undefined (`c` isn't set); just remove `c==EOF &&`. And by NULL, do you mean a NUL character?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic to null-terminate the string is broken. You write a NUL byte after every character *except* the last one. Move the line which writes the NUL to just after the loop.

By the way, I have seen worse variable names than `I_help_Notify_IfNotRead` but not often. What was wrong with `out`?

Answer (score 1):

The null character is not appended at the correct point [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32418472/2410359) & [@Jim Balter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418328/my-implementation-of-fgets-reads-actual-content-as-fgets-does-but-it-reads-garba/32418610#comment52703089_32418328).  That is the main issue.  Suggest

```
if (size > 0) {   
  while(--size>0 && (c=getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    *I_help_Notify_IfNotRead++ = c;
    if (c == '\n') break;
  }
  *I_help_Notify_IfNotRead = '\0';
}
```

Corner case problems:

If `size == 1`, the null character is not written.  (fixed above)

`myfgets()` does not fulfill: "If a read error occurs during the operation, ... a null pointer is returned."  Maybe:

```
if (c == EOF) {
  if (ferror(fp)) return NULL;
  if (feof(fp) && I_help_Notify_IfNotRead == Buffer_address) return NULL;
}
return Buffer_address;
```

Comment: ya i do agree  NULL char was not appended but your second statement  "If a read error occurs during the operation . a null pointer is returned" but myfgets  above will return NULL.in while loop getc()  return the character read as an  unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error and 'c' is checked in ternary operator isn't it ?

Comment: @user4950013  `EOF` is returned when end-of-file or an input error occurs.  Your code returns `NULL` if `EOF` was returned and nothing was read.  Per the spec, if an `EOF` is returned due to an input error, `fgets()` returns `NULL` regardless of the number of characters is previously read.

Comment: @user4950013 BTW, Rather than saying "NULL char", use "null character" or `'\0'`.  Save "NULL" for `NULL`, the "null pointer constant".